# C# Recursivly populate treeview from paths in registry

Tags: c#, recursion, path, treeview, registry

**Question**: How can I recursivly populate my treeview with multiple path values as strings from the registry into treeview nodes using C#?

**What I would like to do**:
Recursivly Populate my treeView1 with string values from each registry value gathered in my list[] array also used for a listBox (listBox1) and ofcourse only adding values from the registry that is not null . I am very grateful for any help or input with this problem.

**How I load my path into treeView1**:

```
private void PopulateTreeView()
        {
            try
            {
                TreeNode rootNode;
                NodeInfo nInfo;

                string path = Global.GetStartUpPath();
                DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(path);
                if (info.Exists)
                {
                    rootNode = new TreeNode(info.Name, 3, 3);
                    rootNode.Name = info.Name;

                    nInfo = new NodeInfo(NodeInfo.Types.Root, info.FullName);
                    rootNode.Tag = nInfo;

                    GetDirectories(info, rootNode);
                    treeView1.Nodes.Add(rootNode);
                    treeView1.SelectedNode = rootNode;
                }

            }
```

**How I set a path**:

```
public static void setStartUpPath(string path)
        {
            //Open the registry key
            RegistryKey rk1 = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software", true);
            //Create a subkey, if not exist
            RegistryKey sk1 = rk1.CreateSubKey(@"Example\Test\Path");

            sk1.SetValue("StartupPath", path);

            sk1.Close();

            _startUpPath = path;
        }
```

**And how I get it**:

```
public static string GetStartUpPath()
    {
        if ( (_startUpPath != null) && (_startUpPath != string.Empty) )
                return _startUpPath;           
        //Check registry
        else
        {
            //Open the registry key
            RegistryKey rk1 = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Example\Test\Path", true);
            if (rk1 == null)
                return string.Empty;

            _startUpPath = (string)rk1.GetValue("StartupPath");
            rk1.Close();
            return _startUpPath;
        }


    }
```

**(If it helps) My method for getting the paths in to a listbox**:

```
public static string[] GetPaths()
        {
            //Open the registry key
            RegistryKey rk1 = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Example\Test\Path\List", true);
            if (rk1 == null)
                return null;

            string[] list = new string[rk1.ValueCount];


            for (int i = 0; i < rk1.ValueCount; i++)
            {
                list[i] = rk1.GetValue(i.ToString()).ToString();
            }
            rk1.Close();
            return list;

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it myself. For others coming here looking for an answer this is how I solved the treeview.

```
        try
        {
            TreeNode rootNode;
            NodeInfo nInfo;

            string[] paths = Global.GetPaths();
            for (int i = 0; i < paths.Length; i++)
            {
                string path = paths[i];
                DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(path);
                if (info.Exists)
                {
                    rootNode = new TreeNode(info.Name, 3, 3);
                    rootNode.Name = info.Name;

                    nInfo = new NodeInfo(NodeInfo.Types.Root, info.FullName);
                    rootNode.Tag = nInfo;

                    GetDirectories(info, rootNode);
                    treeView1.Nodes.Add(rootNode);
                    treeView1.SelectedNode = rootNode;
                }
            }

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //.....
            Logic.Log.write("ERROR PopulateTreeView -" + ex.Message);
        }
```